# Extraneous Library Linkage

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have a question which may be somewhat silly because I'm pretty sure I may know the answer already.

Suppose you have static library A, and dynamic shared object library B and your program C under linux. Suppose that library A calls functions from library B and your program calls functions from library A. Now suppose that all functions that C calls in A make no use of functions in B.

To compile C will it be enough to link just A and omit B and furthermore can your program C be run on a system without library B  installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your program calls functions in A that don't reference B then B is not required either at link or load time, assuming that the functions in A are in separate compilation units, which is usually the case for a library.

The linker will pull the functions from the library that C uses and since none of them call functions in B, B will not be needed.

Comment: ahhh thanks! So the linker is smarter than I initially thought.

Answer (score 4):

Holy placeholder name overload, batman. Let's first replace A, B, and C, with `libstatic`, `libshared`, and `myapp` to make things a little more legible:

> Suppose you have static library `libstatic`, and
>   dynamic shared object library `libshared` and
>   your program `myapp` under linux. Suppose
>   that library `libstatic` calls functions from
>   library `libshared` and your program (`myapp`) calls
>   functions from library `libstatic`. Now suppose
>   that all functions that `myapp` calls in `libstatic`
>   make no use of functions in `libshared`.
>
> To compile `myapp` will it be enough to link
>   just `libstatic` and omit `libshared` and furthermore can
>   your program `myapp` be run on a system
>   without library `libshared` installed?

So the way I understand your question, there is a library `libstatic`, *some* functions in which make use of `libshared`. You want to know: if I don't use *any* of the `libstatic` functions that are dependent on `libshared`, will `myapp` link and run without `libshared`?

The answer is yes, so long as two things are true:

1. The calls you make into `libstatic` do not depend on `libshared` directly *or indirectly*. Meaning that if `myapp` calls a function in `libstatic` which calls another function in `libstatic` which calls a function in `libshared`, then `myapp` is now dependent on `libshared`.
2. The calls you make into `libstatic` do not depend on any function in `libstatic` whose implementation *appears in the same compilation unit* (object file) with a call to `libshared`. The linker brings in code from the static library at the level of object files, not at the level of individual functions. And remember, this dependency is similarly chained, so if you call a function in `foo.o`, and something else in `foo.o` calls a function in `bar.o`, and something in `bar.o` depends on `libshared`, you're toast.

When you link in a static library into an application, only the object files that contain the symbols used (directly or indirectly) are linked. So if it turns out that none of the object files that `myapp` ends up needing from `libstatic` depend on `libshared`, then `myapp` doesn't depend on `libshared`.