# C++: static link not found

Tags: c++

I make a libtest_lib.a file with cmake.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(test)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 98)
set(SOURCE_FILES library.cpp library.h)
add_library(test_lib ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

then in my executable C++ project ,I include the  `#include "library.h"`
and the CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(study)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 98)
set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(study ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(study libtest_lib.a) //libtest_lib.a file under the project path
```

but it fails.

```
/Users/bin381/CLionProjects/study/main.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'library.h' file not found
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703647

Comment: I need to include my `library.h` in my project [static-library-but-i-still-need-headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612027/static-library-but-i-still-need-headers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the include directories as mentioned in the documentation : https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html
Otherwise cmake will not be able to find where to look in for include files.